# Where to store photos in android application

Tags: android, sqldelight

I'd like to do in my android application access to camera and option to take photos.
Where is the best way to store photos?

1. On device in library? And save path to them
2. In localdatabase in blob column? (SqlDelight)
3. Other way?
   Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on how you are going to use them. What's the purpose?

Comment: Android Recommends to store images using MediaStore . So you should use it , it is much alike sql created by android to store all images

Comment: The purpose is store past picture of body and comapre with actual to see difference.
Thanks, I look and this mediastore